# Why would someone want to run an Ethereum node?

Tags: evm, nodejs, nodes, full-node

Is there any financial incentive to run an Ethereum node, or is it primarily for data gathering? Does running a node always preclude the responsibility of validating blocks?

If someone's only motivation to run a node is for profit, what can they do with a node and how?

*(The related question asked something similar during the mining regime, but my question is different because it supposes the new staking regime)*

Comment: we use our own Ethereum nodes because we are trading with bots, so we modify the Ethereum Virtual Machine to make the trading faster or to extract the data the default software doesn't provide. You can make lots of money in automatic trading, so that's a financial incentive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are financial incentives to run an Ethereum node if you're a validator. Besides data gathering, you can also run your own node for the purpose of security and privacy, censorship resistance, decentralization, distributed control, and sovereignty. Running a node does not always preclude the responsibility of validating blocks, but your own node verifies all transactions and blocks. If other nodes experience outages or problems, your node won’t be affected. If someone's only motivation to run a node is for profit, they can also hold ETH put into staking and the person can do that by installing, running, and connecting to other nodes in the P2P network.

See:

https://en.cryptonomist.ch/2022/11/26/what-is-an-ethereum-node-and-how-it-works/

https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/running-your-own-node

Comment: So the only way to profit off an Ethereum node is for the node owner to stake on it?

Comment: You will also receive unburnt transaction fees for blocks you propose, in addition to staking on it. See: https://ethereum.org/en/staking/

Comment: Does running a node mean only you can stake on the node, or you can permit others to stake on your node also and earn a cut from them?

Comment: Validators also receive commission on the staking rewards from their delegators.

Comment: validators, delegators, stakers, none of these words make sense.

Comment: Validators run a validator node to validate transactions and can accept delegators. Delegators delegate, or stake, their share of ETH to validators to earn interest. Both are considered stakers because both stake ETH on the ETH PoS network.

Comment: Is the cost-benefit lower for DIY node validators than staking on an exchange?

Comment: If you can accept the upfront cost, be a DIY node validator. If not, you can stake on an exchange, but you need to be cautious as the exchange can be hacked or become bankrupt in market downturns.

Comment: whats the upfront cost